# What is the difference between using .newInstance() and not using?

Tags: java

I see a lot of java examples connecting to a db, makes a call to `newInstance()`. Some don't use it at all.  I tried both and are working fine.  I couldn't understand why some use and some don't?

```
...
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
...
...
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
...
```

Comment: Just use last option. You don't need to create any instance of the driver. Just needed to load the driver class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *modern* Java, neither of these is needed.

The reason for using `Class.forName` in "the good old days" was that it would run the type initialization code, which would register the driver with JDBC. You don't need to create a new instance of the driver though, so your first example was never required.

However, these days it isn't required - [`DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) uses the standard service provider mechanism to find drivers. I'd be surprised to see any production-quality drivers that didn't support this now.

In *other* cases where you might see code calling `Class.forName()` with or without `newInstance()`, the two are separate calls:

- `Class.forName(String)` is a static method which finds/loads a `Class` object with the specified fully-qualified name... just as if you'd used `Foo.class` at compile-time, but without knowing the name `Foo`
- `Class.newInstance()` is an instance method which creates a new instance of the class represented by the `Class` object which is the target of the method, calling the parameterless constructor. So `Foo.class.newInstance()` is a little bit like `new Foo()` - except again, you don't need to know `Foo` at compile-time (e.g. if you've obtained a `Class` reference via `Class.forName`, or accepted it as a method parameter)

Comment: Now it looks great, +1 for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

This will dynamically load the given class name, if exist else will throw `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

This will do the above in addition to that, will also create a new object/instance of the given class name.

In jdbc, the first one is enough, as we only need to register the jdbc driver, there is no need to create new object/instance explicitly.

You can also, load the jdbc drivers manually by command line options.

```
java -Djdbc.drivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

That just initializes the mentioned class in class loader.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Returns the instance of that class.

In this specific case initialization of Driver class is enough.